# Automatically refresh a standard page layout

Tags: webservices, page-layout, callout, refresh

I have a webservice callout, and therefore I update a field on pagelayout according to the callback. The problem is I have to refresh the page layout (F5) everytime to see the field updated on my page layout. Is there any solution to automatically refresh the page layout?

Comment: are you calling webservice from custom button or something else? if custom button then use javascript to reload VF page

Comment: It's not a VF page, it's a standard pagelayout. The webservice is calling via trigger when meeting some criteria.

Comment: then I am afraid. You don't have another option you need to wait untill webservice update your fields.

Comment: The field is updated in the database.. the only issue is to show the new result on the page layout !!!

Comment: If callout is synchronous then it should reflect the data. I think you are making future callout.  Try to remove @future.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the page refresh itself every couple seconds, minutes, etc... You can do this in JavaScript.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, NUMBEROFMINUTES*60000);
```

Replace the `NUMBEROFMINUTES` with how many minutes you want to wait before the page refreshes by itself.

Comment: Since it is a standard page layout you may want to add a VF page section for the field and then use javascript to refresh periodically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1) you remove the callout from the trigger and add it to a custom button or flow, so that you can display the result in the screen as part of the same transaction.

2) When the field is updated, send an email to the owner (via workflow) to let them know the transaction has completed and that they should refresh the page to see the latest changes.